# A 2D array of objects in a class SFML C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, 2d, sfml

(I apologise if something's wrong, it's my first question)

I'm trying to create a grid of rooms for my game (similarly to Binding of Isaac).

I have a commanding class called 'Station' in which i want to have a 2D array of rooms, which I defined in my class 'Room'.
In my main.cpp I'm using a Room object called currentroom, that I want to pass by reference to a function loadRoom in my Station class. That function would generate all Rooms in the array and pass the middle one back to main.cpp by reference.
I've been tring to make it work with vectors, arrays, arrays of pointers and even new classes designed solely for the purpose of storing Rooms, but nothing seems to have worked. Please help me, these are my 2 classes mentioned before:
Station.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "The Station.h"

class Station
{
public:
    void pause();
    void resume();
    int h,w;
    Station();
    sf::RenderWindow App;
    sf::Image guii;
    sf::Texture player, bgt,   guit, fltilt;
    sf::Font arial;


    void loadSection(Room& currentroom);
};
```

Room.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "The Station.h"

#define n 16
#define m 6
class Station;
class enemy;
class projectile;
class Room
{
public:
    tile floortile[n][m];
    sf::Texture floort,enemyt, dleftt,sht, drightt,dtopt,dbottomt, chestt;
    int chest_max=15;
    int chestcount;
    bool dleft, dright,dtop,dbottom,isempty;
    Room();
    void loadroom(int w, int h);
    std::vector <enemy> enem;
    std::vector <projectile> proj;
    void spawn_enemy(int x,int y);
};
```

I would like the first one to have the array of the latter.
Thank you.

EDIT: 
Ok, here's what I got:
When I simply try to make a 2d array like this:

```
Room sect[10][10];
```

and I put it in a class before the void loadSection, it crashes a second after running.
When I make an object of class Section called 'lvl' in the same place, it only crashes when I try to access a member of a Room, like this:

```
this->lvl->Row[5].Column[5].loadroom(this->w,this->h);
```

However, when I create a vector of vectors, like this:

```
std::vector< vector< Room > > station;
```

it crashes when I try to resize it, no matter if I do it with an initializer, push_back, or vector::resize.

The error is always the same, Application.exe stopped working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to help, we need more specific information about where the problem is (and appropriate code and output). For example, are having an issue passing by reference properly or finding the middle?

Comment: The issue is that when i run it, it stops working unless I remove the array from the Station class. There are no build errors. (In the code above I didn't include any of the versions of the 2d array that I've tried, but all either made program stop working a second after running or they caused a runtime error (unusual way and this kinda stuff).

Comment: @user3104621 Please add any essential information into your question. Putting this as a comment s pretty useless.

Comment: Is this enough info, cause I don't know what else to say.

Comment: @user3104621 You need to use a debugger and find exactly where the problem is, Visual Studio has a great one. If you're new to debugging, looking up breaking points and code stepping.

Comment: @user3104621 The issue πάντα ῥεῖ is highlighting is that you haven't provided the code that's not behaving itself, just the headers (which don't really give much away).

Comment: I thought it would be too much to put my whole 300 lines main.cpp in, and the rest doesn't matter. In main, the only line possibly causing the problems is the one in which I call the function loadSection. Should I paste my main.cpp to the question?

Comment: Also, the problem may be that I just don't know how to put a 2d array of objects into a class.

Comment: @user3104621 You should post the specific part that doesn't work. As for not knowing how to put a 2D array into a class, you've already done exactly that with `tile floortile[n][m]` (although I'd advise using vectors where possible, as you can change/determine their size at runtime)

Comment: Yes, i've done it with tile floortile[n][m], but somehow Room doesn't want to be put in a 2d array.

Comment: @user3104621 What do you mean by "doesn't want to"? What happens when you do? For example, an exception might be thrown if you go out of bounds.

Comment: I'm still learning and I don't know how to handle exceptions yet. However, when I used another class, Section, as an array like this (I'll edit it in the question)it crashes only when I try to access a member of one of the stored Rooms.

Comment: @user3104621 Generally speaking, that's a sign that you're access memory that doesn't belong to you ("Access Violation at 0x??????"). To solve this problem, you need to learn about exceptions and the debugger (Google is a good resource for this).

Comment: Ok, I'll try this tomorrow, I'll go sleep now.

Comment: The most likely cause is that you try to access an element outside the bounds of the 2D array. In order to find the erroneous part of your code you should give a minimal example to us (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, if your debugger doesn't provide you with the line of code, that caused the crash, you should probably just step through the code execution (one instruction at a time).

Comment: Wow was 8-years-ago me bad at asking programming questions, among other things. One of these things being version control (or lack thereof), it doesn't seem possible to ascertain what the root cause of the original problem. My best archaeologic guess is that due to having very little understanding of C++'s value semantics for classes, I was creating way too many copies, and the oldest copy of the code I found looks like a million off-by-one errors in handling of the tile placement. A for effort, F for SO question quality. Closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. I removed the loadRoom function and put its code into the default constructor. The other problem I had with it, was that the sf::Texture operator= overload was causing a crash, so I loaded the textures from files again instead of copying them. I know its wasteful and slow, but I'm going to write it from scratch in Unity in a few months, so I don't care if its optimized or not.